# Refactor implementation

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I'm refactoring a C++ code doing kmean clustering. There are two version of the code:

1. Normal kmean
2. Feature aligned clustering: use slightly different distance metric and update rule.

How should I implement this effectively? Method overloading (this doesn't depend on input though)

OK so this is the pseudocode doing kmean clustering. I need to implement two versions of distance and update function.

```
int* kmean_clustering(vector<double[10]> data)
// each row of data hold one data point
// so we have M data points of 10 dimension
{
    // Split codebook
    // Assignment step
    Find the closest codebook based on distance(distance here can be Euclidean, Mahalanobis, .....)
    //Update step
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code, oterwise how can we suggest how to refector it?

Comment: Is function pointer a good idea? I don't want to have Kmean_Euclidean, Kmean_Mahalanobis, Kmean_blah_blah functions

Answer (score 2):

A well written code is like reading a good novel. That's why Knuth calls it as an art of programming. [This book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201485672) might teach you bottom-up approach of refactoring.